# Is it possible to delete a GET variable with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, get, reset

I have a dynamic search form and when I send a query it remains the values of the query in GET variables.

Now, I have a custom reset button too, that clear the fields, but with surprise I note that the new queries mantains the GET values and carry bad results.

Thanks for help.

Comment: How are you performing the AJAX request? Could you show some code?

Comment: Hi. I'm not using Ajax, just a simple Javascript to reset the fields: function tx_oriconvocatorias_pi1_reset() {
 document.getElementById("cvc[buscar]").value="";
 document.getElementById("cvc[filtro]").selectedIndex = 0;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume that you are having problems because get values stay in the url. so you can use

```
history.pushState(stateObj, "", ('http://localhost/'));
```

by replacing the localhost with your page **link**

Comment: Thanks, this is another interesting way and your answer is related with my question, so I select yours as the accepted answer.

Comment: You are welcome, be advised that this snippet may not be compatible for IE6. There should be a workaround that which you can find with a quick search.

Answer (score 0):

Set the form's `action` attribute to a URL without parameters.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I solved it cleaning the `action` URL.